# Git Tower - how to see remote branches to track

Tags: git-tower

#### Setup:

- Four branches on github
- Only three display in Tower (Git GUI)
- When pulling, three branches are available to pull from (forth not available)
- If we pull on master, the fourth branch doesn't show

---

#### Question:

How do we get Tower to see the fourth branch so we can work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, worked it out:

1. Fetch from Github (origin) instead of pulling
2. The remote branch will appear in the side bar under REMOTES
3. Drag the branch you would like to track locally onto BRANCHES in the sidebar

Now you can right click the newly dragged branch and check it out.